# How to access pairs in C++?

Tags: c++, std-pair

I don't know how to name this question more properly, but this is it, basically:

I've made a pair `pair<int, int> P[20000]` and I'm using `P.first` and `P.second` but...

When I try to input into P.first, like `cin >> P.first[i]` (i is the counter) it doesn't let me. It calls an error when compiling. How do I fix this?

Edit: Got the answer to my previous question, but new question: I'm trying to run a descending sort on P.second like so

```
sort(P.second, P.second + x, greater<int>());
```

but it causes another compilation error. I understand why this happens, but how do I fix it. Basically, say that the pairs are `{{0,0}, {3,2}, {4,-1}, {5,1}}` my desired result is `{{3,2}, {5,1}, {0,0}, {4,-1}}`.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `P` is an array of pairs, not a pair of arrays.

Comment: `P` is an array. You need to use subscripting to name an element *first*.

Comment: So how would I fix that? How do input into the first part of the i'th pair? @molbdnilo

Comment: @StoryTeller How would I go about doing this? Sorry, I'm not really used to using pairs.

Comment: @Astoria The elements of the array are `P[i]` (like all arrays), so each `P[i]` is a pair.

Comment: @molbdnilo Is it possible to input specifically into one element of the pair, or not? Thanks.

Comment: The sort should goes to another question.

Comment: @lamandy Sure, I'll do that.

Comment: @lamandy Won't let me for 3 days, unfortunately can't do that.

Comment: Open another question for that new one, don't reuse this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer to second question:

```
//if you want sort P[] by using first as primiry key and second as second key
std::sort(P, P + 20000, std::greater<std::pair<int, int>>());
//if you wang sort p[] by second only
typedef std::pair<int, int> IIPair;
std::sort(P, P + 20000, [](const IIPair &lhs, const IIPair &rhs){ return lhs.second > rhs.second;});
```

Answer (score 11):

The indexing is wrong in your code.
To correct it, use `cin>>P[i].first` instead of `cin>>P.first[i]`.

To sort your entries, use `std:sort` as following:

```
using Pair = std::pair<int, int>;
auto&& comparator =  [](const Pair& lhs, const Pair& rhs){ return lhs.second > rhs.second;};
std::sort( P, P + 20000, comparator );
```

See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) for more information about `std::pair` and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for more information about `std::sort`.

**Note:** You will need to include `<algorithm>` header file to use `std:sort` function.

[Visit here to see an working example](https://ideone.com/NnsKZO).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Didn't know it was that simple.

Comment: Alright, I'll close it when it lets me in 3 minutes.  By the way, if you have spare time, can you answer my other question: how do you sort by elements of one half of the pair? I would ask another question but StackExchange doesn't let me for 3 days. @cse

Answer (score 0):

Since `P` is an array of pairs, its elements `P[i]` are pairs.
Since `P[i]` is a pair, you can access its parts with `P[i].first` and `P[i].second`.